# For Oracle SQl when doing select query need to fill/copy rows from Friday date to weekend dates (Saturday and Sunday)

Tags: oracle

Have a query that returns a result set by date and product id. Output can have the same date for multiple product ids. Looking for a way to fill in data from Friday dates to weekend dates.

Example data from source table:

| Date | Product ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1/6/2023 | 1 |
| 1/6/2023 | 2 |
| 1/6/2023 | 3 |
| 1/9/2023 | 4 |
| 1/9/2023 | 5 |
| 1/9/2023 | 6 |

Tried:

```
With CTE as
(SELECT 
    MIN(date'2023-01-06' + level - 1) min_d,
    MAX(date'2023-01-09' + level - 1) max_d
FROM   dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (date'2023-01-01' - date'2023-12-31' + 1)
)
SELECT 
    SALES_DATE,
    NVL(PRODUCT_ID, LAST_VALUE(PRODUCT_ID) IGNORE NULLS OVER (ORDER BY SALES_DATE, PRODUCT_ID ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)) AS PRODUCT_ID    
   FROM (
     SELECT 
        min_d + level - 1 as d
      FROM CTE
    CONNECT BY min_d + level - 1 <= max_d
  ) dt LEFT JOIN Source_Table ST ON (dt.d = ST.SALES_DATE)
GROUP BY PRODUCT_ID, d
ORDER BY SALES_DATE, PRODUCT_ID
```

Output Result:

| Date | Product ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1/6/2023 | 1 |
| 1/6/2023 | 2 |
| 1/6/2023 | 3 |
| 1/7/2023 | 1 |
| 1/8/2023 | 1 |
| 1/9/2023 | 4 |
| 1/9/2023 | 5 |
| 1/9/2023 | 6 |

Expected output in select query:

| Date | Product ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1/6/2023 | 1 |
| 1/6/2023 | 2 |
| 1/6/2023 | 3 |
| 1/7/2023 | 1 |
| 1/7/2023 | 2 |
| 1/7/2023 | 3 |
| 1/8/2023 | 1 |
| 1/8/2023 | 2 |
| 1/8/2023 | 3 |
| 1/9/2023 | 4 |
| 1/9/2023 | 5 |
| 1/9/2023 | 6 |

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, not just Oracle's dialect, result sets are non-deterministically ordered unless you have an `ORDER BY` clause. Therefore, it is unclear why you expect one row to correlate with a previous value when they appear to be unconnected.

If you simply want to number the rows from 1 to 3 in the order of `product_id` for each day and then fill in the blanks for the missing days then you can generate a calendar of all the days and then use a `PARTITION`ed `OUTER JOIN` to `source_table` and `PARTITION` on the `ROW_NUMBER` for each row:

```sql
SELECT d.dt AS sales_date,
       LAST_VALUE(s.product_id) IGNORE NULLS OVER (
         PARTITION BY s.rn
         ORDER BY d.dt
       ) AS product_id
FROM   (
         SELECT min_dt + LEVEL - 1 AS dt
         FROM   (
           SELECT MIN(sales_date) AS min_dt,
                  MAX(sales_date) AS max_dt
           FROM   source_table
         )
         CONNECT BY min_dt + LEVEL - 1 <= max_dt
       ) d
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (
         SELECT sales_date,
                product_id,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sales_date ORDER BY product_id) AS rn
         FROM   source_table
       ) s
       PARTITION BY (s.rn)
       ON (d.dt = s.sales_date);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE source_table (sales_date, Product_ID) AS
  SELECT DATE '2023-01-06', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-01-06', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-01-06', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-01-09', 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-01-09', 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-01-09', 6 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| SALES_DATE | PRODUCT_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-06 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 2023-01-07 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 2023-01-08 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 2023-01-09 00:00:00 | 4 |
| 2023-01-06 00:00:00 | 2 |
| 2023-01-07 00:00:00 | 2 |
| 2023-01-08 00:00:00 | 2 |
| 2023-01-09 00:00:00 | 5 |
| 2023-01-06 00:00:00 | 3 |
| 2023-01-07 00:00:00 | 3 |
| 2023-01-08 00:00:00 | 3 |
| 2023-01-09 00:00:00 | 6 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/O9WvprUM)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a way to fill in data **from Friday dates to weekend dates** which implies that you will always have Friday data available and you want to **fill in the data only for Weekends** but **not for other missing dates** then you can generate the dates using `CONNECT BY`, check if they are weekends using `TO_CHAR` and fill in the data as follows:

```
SELECT ALL_DATES.DT AS SALES_DATE, S.PRODUCT_ID AS PRODUCT_ID
  FROM (  SELECT
            MIN_DT + LEVEL - 1                                             AS DT,
            TO_CHAR(MIN_DT + LEVEL - 1, 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') AS DOW
          FROM (  SELECT 
                    MIN(SALES_DATE) AS MIN_DT,
                    MAX(SALES_DATE) AS MAX_DT
                    FROM SOURCE_TABLE
               ) CONNECT BY MIN_DT + LEVEL - 1 <= MAX_DT
       ) ALL_DATES
      LEFT OUTER JOIN SOURCE_TABLE S 
        ON ( ALL_DATES.DT - DECODE(ALL_DATES.DOW, 'SAT', 1, 'SUN', 2, 0) = S.SALES_DATE )
 ORDER BY ALL_DATES.DT, S.PRODUCT_ID;
```

[DB<>Fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/b1pYrB6v)

Comment: Thank you both for the quick response. Much appreciated.